# how to remove a specific element in the tuple?

Tags: python

how to remove a specific element in the tuple?

for example:

```
      L={('a','b','c','d'):1,('a','b','c','e'):2}

      remove='b'
```

I want to get a result of :

```
     {('a','c','d'):1,('a','c','e'):2}
```

Comment: Can you provide some better context on why you have such structure? Wat if after removing one element 2 keys become the same?

Answer (score 3):

```
In [20]: L={('a','b','c','d'):1,('a','b','c','e'):2}

In [21]: {tuple(y for y in x if y != "b"):L[x] for x in L}
Out[21]: {('a', 'c', 'd'): 1, ('a', 'c', 'e'): 2}
```

or using `filter()`:

```
In [24]: { tuple(filter(lambda y:y!="b",x)) : L[x] for x in L}
Out[24]: {('a', 'c', 'd'): 1, ('a', 'c', 'e'): 2}
```

Comment: Doing so you could render some keys duplicate and then they would overwrite each other.

Comment: list comprehensions are preferred over filters

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I just thought it was worth the warning. My guess is that he should have been using another data structure in the first place.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I think generator expressions should be preferred over list comprehensions?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: true, but then you'd lose multiple-pass iterability

Answer (score 0):

You could create an updated version of the dictionary using a dictionary comprehension expression:

```
L = {('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'): 1, ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'): 2, ('f', 'g', 'h'): 3}

remove='b'
L = {tuple(i for i in k if i != remove) if remove in k else k:v for (k,v) in L.items()}

print L
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'c', 'e'): 2, ('a', 'c', 'd'): 1, ('f', 'g', 'h'): 3}
```

As you can see it, it leaves items without the element in their tuple key alone.